# Probleme with httptest postForm in golang

Tags: go

i receive a response body "bad request" with "httptest.Client().Postform"

```
type testServer struct {
    *httptest.Server
}

func newTestServer(t *testing.T, h http.Handler) *testServer {
    ts := httptest.NewTLSServer(h)

    jar, err := cookiejar.New(nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    ts.Client().Jar = jar

    ts.Client().CheckRedirect = func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        return http.ErrUseLastResponse
    }
    return &testServer{ts}
}
func (ts *testServer) postForm(t *testing.T, urlPath string, form url.Values) (int, http.Header, string) {
    rs, err := ts.Client().PostForm(ts.URL+urlPath, form)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rs.Body.Close()
    body, err := io.ReadAll(rs.Body)

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    bytes.TrimSpace(body)

    return rs.StatusCode, rs.Header, string(body)
}
```

I don't know where is the problem, i have also verified the url it's correct.
Always badrequest with POST but with GET request it's works fine.

this is the handler object :

```
func (app *application) routes() http.Handler {
    router := httprouter.New()
router.NotFound = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        app.notFound(w)
    })
dynamic := alice.New(app.sessionManager.LoadAndSave, noSurf, app.Authenticated)
    router.Handler(http.MethodGet, "/", dynamic.ThenFunc(app.home))
    router.Handler(http.MethodGet, "/user/signup", dynamic.ThenFunc(app.userSignup))
    router.Handler(http.MethodPost, "/user/signup", dynamic.ThenFunc(app.userSignupPost))
    standart := alice.New(app.recoverPanic, app.logRequest, securityHeaders)

    return standart.Then(router)
}
```

the test function :https://go.dev/play/p/k45-JYTYCOS

the app.userSignupPost:

```
func (app *application) userSignupPost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var form userSignupForm
    err := app.decodPostForm(r, &form)
    if err != nil {
        app.clientError(w, http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    form.CheckField(validator.NotBlank(form.Name), "name", "this field must not be blank")
    form.CheckField(validator.NotBlank(form.Email), "email", "this field must not be blank")
    form.CheckField(validator.Matches(form.Email, validator.EmailRX), "email", "this field must be a valid email address")
    form.CheckField(validator.NotBlank(form.Password), "password", "this field must not be blank")
    form.CheckField(validator.MinChars(form.Password, 8), "password", "password must bee at least 8 caracter long")
    if !form.Valid() {
        data := app.newTemplateData(r)
        data.Form = form
        app.render(w, http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, "signup.tmpl.html", data)
        return
    }
    err = app.users.Insert(form.Name, form.Email, form.Password)
    if err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, models.ErrDuplicateEmail) {
            form.AddFieldError("email", "Email already exist")

            data := app.newTemplateData(r)
            data.Form = form
            app.render(w, http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, "signup.tmpl.html", data)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("error user postform")
            app.serverError(w, err)
        }
        return
    }
    app.sessionManager.Put(r.Context(), "flash", "Signup Successful. Please log in")
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/user/login", http.StatusSeeOther)
}
```

Comment: Your error probably depends on how you defined your `http.Handler` object

Comment: `http.Client.PostForm()` adds the header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-url-encoded` - have you tried a simple `Post()` as well (which will not add that header unless you explicitly specify it)?

Comment: Can you also please supply the code for `app.userSignupPost()`?

Comment: updated the post app.userSignupPost() @SandyCash

Comment: When I changed to simple Post() it's gives me 307

Comment: @FlissiHamed - 307 is `http.StatusTemporaryRedirect` in go - you should see if you can trace where that could be getting returned, because I don't see any place in your `userSignupPost()` that should return that - your only redirect in there (`http.StatusSeeOther`) should come back as a 303.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using https://github.com/justinas/alice to register handlers - you don't want to do this.  That package is for middleware chaining - e.g. "before all requests to this URL, first authenticate the request" - you'd put the authentication into a middleware function and then add it to the chain.

So every `POST /user/signup` request is getting passed first to `app.userSignup()` (what you are using to handle GET requests).  This is because calling `alice.ThenFunc()` appends the passed handler to the chain and *then returns the entire chain* as a handler - you need to read [this part of the Alice docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/justinas/alice#Chain.Then) carefully before using it.

Replace this line:

```
router.Handler(http.MethodPost, "/user/signup", dynamic.ThenFunc(app.userSignupPost))
```

with

```
router.Handler(http.MethodPost, "/user/signup", http.HandlerFunc(app.userSignupPost))
```

You may not need the additional decoration of `http.HandlerFunc()` - try it with and without to see what works.  I cannot say for sure without knowing what the body of `app.userSignupPost()` looks like (same for the other handler functions as well).

You'll then need to do the same for the other handler registration lines - you shouldn't be using middleware chaining for your end handlers.  An `http.Handler` is used for saying, "send any request to path /PP/ppp with method XXXX to this function."  Middleware chaining is for preprocessing (authentication, authorization, etc.) - a whole host of things can be done there, but end request handling shouldn't be one of them.

I'm still curious if your use of `PostForm()` is going to cause you issues for the reason I cited in my comment on your question - try a raw `Post()` and see if the behavior differs, but after refactoring to take out the `alice` goop (at least temporarily).  When testing a handler, I'd start off with a much more minimal approach - test that the handler itself works before muddying the waters with both `alice` and what looks like [this package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter).

Comment: I m just following a book of Alex Edwards "Let's Go". And i'm stuck in the http test server .

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the problem , the session cookie are not the same for get and post request. i don't know why it has changed.They use the same http.Client()